# How do I use a map in Minecraft PE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft PE v1.1.2 on iOS, and I'm trying to use a map. I'm in creative mode so I can select an empty map or an empty locator map from my inventory and place it in my hot bar.

But when I select the empty map or locator map, the game presents a "Create Map" button. When I tap the button, instead of my character holding a map of my world in its hand, all I see is that my character has dropped an icon on the ground looking like a piece of paper.

All the tutorials online show the character get holding a large sheet of paper which shows a map of all explored regions in the world. But these videos and tutorials are from older versions of the game.

Was this feature removed? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. You can only *read* your map if you're in first-person view.

So I needed to go into settings and adjust the POV the interface presents.

Comment: Could you please accept your answer so it doesn't come up as an unanswered question that people might try to answer?

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this is having the "Hide Hand" setting enabled. Hiding the hand has the side effect of preventing proper map behavior. After turning this setting off, I was able to properly use and fill a map on Minecraft Bedrock v1.16 on iPad.

Answer (score 0):

The “Create Map” button should work normally. If you tapped the map icon in the hotbar instead of tapping the “Create Map” button, it would drop the item instead.

Sometimes there is a glitch where one item continuously gets dropped. I fix this by tapping the inventory button (…) and it stops for me.

The feature hasn't been removed it might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

When you drop the item, you’re supposed to collect it. Then you pick it up again and it appears in your inventory. After that you can put the map in your hot bar and use it.